# Telegram api: how to forward an album

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Does anyone know how can I forward an album (which contains multiple medias in it) with telegram api since `forwardMessage` only gets a `message_id`, I know this is possible because my friend uses some package in python and he can do that but I couldn't find anything on official telegram docs

Comment: Your question is rather implementation independent. I suggest to remove the tags for the libraries `python-telegram-bot` and `pyTelegramBotAPI` as well as the `php-telegram-bot` tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not method in the bot API which let's you do this easily. You'll have to catch all the messages in the media group and resend the media as album via `sendMediaGroup`.

Comment: But sending via `sendMediaGroup` doesnt share the original sender and will send the message with my bot name

Comment: If you want the original sender to display, you'll have to forward the messages one by one. AFAIK they won't be displayed as album in this case though.